# Internally prefix all paths with culture?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Internationalized user visible URLs (all on one server):

```
http://example.us/example/path
http://example.de/beispiel/pfad
```

The URL paths should translate *internally* to (for further processing with `mod_rewrite`):

```
/en_US/example/path
/de_DE/beispiel/pfad
```

What's a good method to add a culture prefix *once* to a path?

Answer (score 1):

> What's a good method to add a culture prefix once to a path?

The answer is: not at all. If you don't want your users to *know* that your structure is like that, then don't show it to them. That means, when you get a request for `.com.br`, you internally check the `HTTP_HOST`, and assign a *variable* to your script, which can then execute based on the language.

To be perfectly honest, I think `mod_rewrite` is a waste of time for this. If your site is written in any half-decent scripting language, you can have your script lookup the `HTTP_HOST` in a database, which matches to a language, and you can continue from there. `mod_rewrite` (and thus most `.htaccess` directives) don't really scale dynamically: what if, when they hit the `.com` version of your website, you want to lookup their IP and redirect them to the most appropriate suffix based on their approximate location? You'll have a tough time doing that with just `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: There is an existing Symfony app which expects paths with the prefix. It then rewrites them further. Really I don't want to change that.

Comment: Just updated the question; forgot to mention that paths are internationalized. The prefix is needed to avoid ambiguities (some words have different meanings in different cultures).

Comment: Well, in the end I did pretty much what you suggested: I revamped the internal routing of the application. Now the router of the application determines the culture from the domain name. By the way, I noticed that you wrote: *"If you don't want your users to know that your structure is like that, then don't show it to them"*. I think there is a misunderstanding: My original idea of using `mod_rewrite` was exactly to *not* reveal the culture prefix. Only the application should see it. In the past, it was user visible, thus redundant as culture is already encoded in the domain name.